# Check the differentiablity of $\theta :\mathbb R^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> For , $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ with $(x,y)\not =(0,0)$ , let $\theta=\theta(x,y)$ be the unique real number such that $-\pi<\theta \le\pi$ and $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta)$ , where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then the resulting function $\theta :\mathbb R^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb R$ is
>
> (A) differentiable.
>
> (B) continuous but not differentiable.
>
> (C) bounded but not continuous.
>
> (D) neither bounded nor continuous.

Here , $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$. So it is differentiable in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. So option (A) is correct.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

> Trace the unit circle multiple times around and keep track of the value of $\theta$. How does it change when you're around the point $-1$? (Remember, it's the unique value of the angle *between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.*)

Comment: I can't understand..Please elaborate..

Comment: No more, any more than this is giving away the answer.

Comment: @Panja717 Choose several points close to (-1,0) with y coordinates both positive and negative and compute $\theta$.  Try points closer and closer to that point.  What do you notice?