# Continuity and differentiability:

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

For $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ with $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, let $\theta=\theta(x,y)$ be the unique real number such that -$\pi\lt\theta\le\pi$ and $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then is the resulting function $\theta:\Bbb R^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}\to \Bbb R$ continuous and differentiable?

I have confusion about the definition of the function theta. How to check the continuity and differentiability of this function.

Comment: $\theta(x,y)$ is the angle that the line from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: yes, now it is easy to check the continuity and differentiability of this function. thank you sir you have cleared my confusions

Comment: What happens at $(-1,0)$? Is it continuous there?

Comment: Sir i don't know whether it is continuous at (-1,0) or not. If you know then please let me know the answer

Comment: Just telling you the answer has very little value. I'm of the belief that if you find the answer yourself, through a little guidance, you will come away from it wiser than if I had told you the answer. So, without further ado: for a _very small_, positive number that I shall call $\epsilon$, what is $\theta(-1, \epsilon)$? What is $\theta(-1, -\epsilon)$?

Comment: Sir, by your hint i understood that  θ is a function from the set of points (x,y) to an inclination of the line joining (0,0) to (x,y) so the function definition is θ(x,y)=θ implies θ(x,y)=arctan(y/x). The limit of this function does not exist for x=0 hence the function θ is not continuous for -π<θ<=π. At the point θ(−1,ϵ) it is continuous. Is it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the differentiablity of $\theta :\mathbb R^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616557/check-the-differentiablity-of-theta-mathbb-r2-setminus-0-0-to-mathbb)